# Android: Not able to store location in SharedPreference

Tags: android, location, sharedpreferences

Here, I'm using the current location of the user as well as the a location which is stored previously and showing path between them.
I'm able to get the correct current location but the location I'm trying to store permanently in Shared Preferences are just getting stored until application is running. Once the application is removed and opened again the saved location gets initialised back to 0.0.

I want to store latitude and longitude permanently once after user press save/change location button.

Here's the code:

```
public class Fragment_ReachHome extends Fragment {

WebView wv;
ProgressDialog pg;
Background bg;
AlertDialog.Builder alert;
ConnectionDetector cd;
MediaPlayer exceptionNotifier;
boolean isInternetPresent = false;



LocationManager locationManager;
LocationListener locationListener;
float latitude;
float longitude;
Location loc;


public static float savelati, savelongi;
Boolean islocationmanagerrequested = false;
Button bsaveorchangeloc, bshowsavedloc;
SharedPreferences pref;
SharedPreferences.Editor edit;
Boolean islocsaved = false, isbpressed = false;

public  Fragment_ReachHome() {}

 @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_reach_home, container, false);

        wv=(WebView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.webView1);
        alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        cd = new ConnectionDetector(getActivity());

        locationManager = (LocationManager) getActivity()
                .getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);






        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Loading... Please Wait..", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


    locationListener = new LocationListener() { //-----X0-- THIS SHOULD ALWAYS COME FIRST THEN X1 SHOULD BE WRITTEN

            @Override
            public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            } 

            @Override
            public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                loc = location;

                latitude = Float.valueOf((float) loc.getLatitude());
                longitude = Float.valueOf((float) loc.getLongitude());

                if(isbpressed){
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "on loc change", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


                }

                bg = new Background();
                bg.execute();


            }
        };
         try {
                isInternetPresent = cd.isConnectingToInternet();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), e.toString(),
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        if(isInternetPresent){
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                    LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0,
                    locationListener);



            }else{

                 exceptionNotifier = MediaPlayer.create(getActivity(), R.raw.notify);
                    exceptionNotifier.start();
                    alert.setTitle("Alert!"); 

                    alert.setMessage("Internet Not Present..! ");
                    alert.setCancelable(true);
                    alert.setPositiveButton("Ok!",
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                        int which) {
                                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                    exceptionNotifier.release();

                                }
                            }).show();

            }





        pref = this.getActivity().getSharedPreferences("", 0);
        edit=pref.edit();
        bsaveorchangeloc =(Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.button1);
        bshowsavedloc =(Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.button2);
        islocsaved = pref.getBoolean("locsaved", false);
        bsaveorchangeloc.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                progress();
                 try {
                        isInternetPresent = cd.isConnectingToInternet();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), e.toString(),
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }

                if(isInternetPresent){
                    //ONLY AFTER X0 THIS MUST BE WRITTEN

                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Saving Location!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                            LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0,
                            locationListener);
                isbpressed = true;
                islocationmanagerrequested = true;

                savelati = pref.getFloat("latestlati", Float.valueOf((float) loc.getLatitude())); //giving default value as 0
                savelongi= pref.getFloat("latestlongi", Float.valueOf((float) loc.getLatitude()));


                edit.putBoolean("locsaved", true);
                edit.commit();


                if(islocationmanagerrequested){
                    locationManager.removeUpdates(locationListener);
                    }
                 pg.dismiss();


                    }else{

                         exceptionNotifier = MediaPlayer.create(getActivity(), R.raw.notify);
                            exceptionNotifier.start();
                            alert.setTitle("Alert!"); 

                            alert.setMessage("Internet Not Present..! ");
                            alert.setCancelable(true);
                            alert.setPositiveButton("Ok!",
                                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                                        @Override
                                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                                int which) {
                                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                            exceptionNotifier.release();

                                        }
                                    }).show();


                    }

            }
        });

        bshowsavedloc.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), savelati+","+savelongi, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        });


        wv.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        wv.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        wv.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
        wv.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        wv.setWebViewClient(new MyWebClient());


        return rootView;
    }


 public void progress(){
        pg = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
        pg.setTitle("");
        pg.setMessage("Please Wait.........");
        pg.setCancelable(false);
        pg.setIndeterminate(true);
        pg.show();
    }

 class Background extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>
    {

        @SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub


                try{
                    if(islocsaved){
                    wv.loadUrl("http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr="+savelati+","+savelongi+"&daddr="+loc.getLatitude()+","+loc.getLongitude());
                    }else{
                         pg.dismiss();

                        exceptionNotifier = MediaPlayer.create(getActivity(), R.raw.notify);
                        exceptionNotifier.start();
                        alert.setTitle("Alert!"); 

                        alert.setMessage("Your home location is not saved yet..! ");
                        alert.setCancelable(true);
                        alert.setPositiveButton("Ok!",
                                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                                    @Override
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                            int which) {
                                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                        exceptionNotifier.release();

                                    }
                                }).show();
                    }
                    }catch(Exception e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }




            return null;
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), latitude+","+longitude, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            locationManager.removeUpdates(locationListener);

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {

            progress();

        }
    }
     public class MyWebClient extends WebViewClient
        {
            @Override
            public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
            }

            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                view.loadUrl(url);
                return true;

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);

                         pg.dismiss();

            }
        }





}
```

Please let me know the correct changes in the code to get store the location permanently...

Comment: Your problem is you always get value of pref but where you put your `Lat` and `Long` in pref?

Comment: @SimplePlan Sir can u please suggest the correct changes to be done in the code?

Comment: @Golu I'm not getting any error or exception looking forward for some logical correction in the code.

Comment: i saw your code but there is no line for

pref.putFloat("latestlati", Float.valueOf((float) loc.getLatitude())); //giving default value as 0
        i= pref.putFloat("latestlongi", Float.valueOf((float) loc.getLatitude()));

Comment: @GovindRathod Sir where to put this code can u please be little clear please, it would be a great help

Comment: yes @SiddharthSachdeva ther is not code for the put value in preferance so it will only getting the default 0 value which did you set.

Answer (score 1):

You can saved value in `preference` on `onPause()` or any `Button click` event where you want using below code.

```
 edit.putFloat("latestlati", Float.valueOf((float) loc.getLatitude()))
 edit.putFloat("latestlongi", Float.valueOf((float) loc.getLatitude())); 

 edit.putBoolean("locsaved", true);
 edit.commit();
```

You can get saved value from `preference` on `onResume()` using below code.

```
  savelati = pref.getFloat("latestlati", 0.0); 
  savelongi= pref.getFloat("latestlongi", 0.0);

  islocsaved=edit.getBoolean("locsaved", true);
```

and for more information go to [Android Shared preferences example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23024831/android-shared-preferences-example) or http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidFileBasedPersistence/article.html

Comment: Tried your way, I'm getting error in onResume : http://prntscr.com/3l534n

see the link and please remember I'm using Fragments

Comment: @SiddharthSachdeva post your all error in your question.

Comment: Sir, I'm getting this error after implementing your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to save the value of longitide and latitude first in the shareprefrences.

```
 edit.putFloat("latestlati", Float.valueOf((float) loc.getLatitude());
 edit.putFloat("latestlongi", Float.valueOf((float) loc.getLongitude);
```

Answer (score 0):

For the better suggestion you have to take your SharedPreferance instance globally

then in your  `onLocationChanged(Location location)` change method you can do this code

```
edit.putFloat("latestlati", Float.valueOf((float) loc.getLatitude()))
edit.putFloat("latestlongi", Float.valueOf((float) loc.getLatitude())); 

edit.putBoolean("locsaved", false);
edit.commit();
```

So, that every location change your value for the location is updated and after come to your activity you always get the refresh/latest value.

with `onCreate() or onResume()` you can get the

```
savelati = pref.getFloat("latestlati", 0.0); 
savelongi= pref.getFloat("latestlongi", 0.0);

islocsaved=edit.getBoolean("locsaved", false);
```

Comment: Ok, if struct some where then tell me for further implementation.

Comment: hey mitra don't tell sir.. Strongly welcome anytime.

Comment: I have done this in onResume: public void onResume() {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   
   savelati = pref.getFloat("latestlati", (float) 0.0); 
   savelongi= pref.getFloat("latestlongi", (float) 0.0);

   islocsaved=((SharedPreferences) edit).getBoolean("locsaved", true);
  super.onResume();
 }

since the code you were suggesting giving me syntax error

Comment: implemented your way and getting force close :/

Comment: did you preference initialization is perfect right ? if problem is there when null pointer.
hope your type cast for your lat long is perfect right ?
now What is logcat saying for the error. ?

Comment: Buddy can I have your e- mail id so that i can mail u everything or u can join me on team viewer please, it would be a great help

Comment: Problem is in OnResume most probably in type casting only.

Comment: ok greate, to caught the error,
fine error because it return the value in too much digits after the point (.),  that why problem in type casting

Comment: No, I didn't got your point over it, what changes I have to make?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54089/discussion-between-govind-rathod-and-siddharth-sachdeva).

Comment: @SiddharthSachdeva please post your logcat once with the error.

Comment: and try the debug once after tell where it the problem in your code

Comment: there is no major issue which you struct on.

Comment: I'm on the chat please come there